# CKFINDER don't find my folder

Tags: php, configuration, upload, directory, ckfinder

I have a small problem at the initial configuration.

I installed CKFinder, the "Browse Server" button is added normally, but when I clicked, instead of opening up the tree no file appears in the left tree.

Here is an overview of my tree:

./admin/ckeditor/

./admin/ckfinder/

./custom/img/ (the folder containing the images)

I configured CKFinder / config.php as follows:

```
$baseUrl = '../../custom/';
```

[...]

```
$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
        'name' => 'Images',
        'url' => $baseUrl . 'img',
        'directory' => $baseDir . 'img',
        'maxSize' => 0,
        'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
        'deniedExtensions' => '');
```

And yet, it does not work! Can someone help me? Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

$baseUrl = '/ckfinder/userfiles/'; 
$baseDir = resolveUrl($baseUrl);

This helped me.